# Initialising File in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I use a FutureBuilder in flutter that is calling `getSingleFile()` from the flutter cache manager library. (https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cache_manager)

I am worried that this could return null so the futureBuilder `AsyncSnapshot.hasData` will always be false.

To overcome this I was thinking of wrapping this in a function that will check if the result of `getSingleFile()` is null and if it is will return `File("")` instead.

Is it safe to initialise a `File("")` like this?

Answer (score 0):

Initializing a file with an empty path will *probably* throw an error and *might* do something screwy with the file system, so either way, it isn't very safe.

If I may offer an alternative suggestion, instead of checking `snapshot.hasData`, instead check `snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done`. That will return true when the future completes regardless of what value it returned.

Comment: Ended up wrapping it in a method that throws an exception if the file is null. Your answer was helpful thuogh!